# HTML emails not sending (Exp:resso Store v1.6.5)

Tags: expresso-store

For some reason, Exp:resso is not sending HTML emails. It sends plain text emails fine, and ExpressionEngine's Communicate is able to send HTML emails no problem.

I've trawled through the settings but can't find anything wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If plain-text emails are being sent and EE is also sending HTML emails then what's likely is that they're being sent but not reaching their destination for some reason. The best approach here is to use an SMTP sending service such as [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) which is not only more reliable in delivery but also able to provide you with information if there is a problem with the send for some reason. From this you'll be able to find out what the problem is.

I'm pretty sure it'll only be a minor detail. There's no reason why HTML emails wouldn't be getting through and giving things a test I can confirm they send fine from my local setup.